# SharePoint 2007: Web Part Zones

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint 2007 where is the file that holds the web part zones and layout of them and how do you go about changing it?

For Example: I have my main site and several sites underneath the main site. Right now the sites have the default web zone parts/layout for them. How do you make it the web zone parts is different for each Site/Masterpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the web part zones are derived from their page layouts. You can use sharepoint designer to open the page layouts from their respective site.

open sharepoint designer, inside the library open the catalogs/masterpage folder to view the various page layouts.

You can also use sharepoint designer to create new page layouts.